# Symfony 2.8 - How to handle datatype of a column different in formBuilder and entity file

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-eventdispatcher

In the form builder I have added field with:

```
type : ChoiceType
multiple : true
```

In the entityfile that column is defined as:

```
Type : string
```

The same column in database table contains type text.

Now I want to insert values selected in form field as comma separated string.

But in below steps it is not allowing to submit the form and throwing error.

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Here, the system is not setting any data of the field from `$request` to `$form`

```
$form->isValid()
```

So, this is not allowing to submit form and, also throws an error.

So, what I need to my data works in the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a DataTransformer. This will allow you to transform the array from the form into a string. Check [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)

Comment: Can you please give me an example how I can use it

Comment: Just see the link which I posted! The simple example is exactly what you are looking for.